# what to do with "gvfs-backends"?

Tags: gvfs

I recently updated my Ubuntu-mate 18.4 to 20.4.
A few days later, when Ubuntu was started, a warning appeared indicating that it should install "gvfs-backends", but, when pressing "install", a warning appears indicating that this software can cause problems and that it does not come from a reliable source .
What should I do?
I include requested commands and their outputs:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i gvfs
ii  gvfs:amd64                                    1.44.1-1ubuntu1                       amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - GIO module
ii  gvfs-common                                   1.44.1-1ubuntu1                       all          userspace virtual filesystem - common data files
ii  gvfs-daemons                                  1.44.1-1ubuntu1                       amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - servers
ii  gvfs-fuse                                     1.44.1-1ubuntu1                       amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - fuse server
ii  gvfs-libs:amd64                               1.44.1-1ubuntu1                       amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - private libraries
```

```
apt-cache policy gvfs-backends
gvfs-backends:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  1.44.1-1ubuntu1
  Tabla de versión:
     1.44.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

```
$ grep -r "^deb " /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-proposed restricted main universe multiverse
```

After following your indications, I repeated:

```
$ grep -r "^deb " /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"

/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main
```

to the command:

`sudo apt-get install gvfs-backend`

The answer (Google-translated to English), was:

```
Reading package list ... Done
Creating dependency tree
Reading the status information ... Done.
Do not can instal some pack. This may mean that
you asked for an impossible situation or, if you are using the distribution
unstable, that some required packages have not yet been created or have been pulled from "Incoming".
The following information can help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  gvfs-backends: Depends: libsmbclient (> = 2: 4.10.0 + dfsg) but it won't install
E: Problems could not be corrected, you have retained broken packages.
```

---

````
enrique@enrique-PC:~$ sudo aptitude install gvfs-backends
Se instalarán los siguiente paquetes NUEVOS:      
  gvfs-backends libcdio-cdda2{a} libcdio-paranoia2{a} libldb2{a} 
  libpython3.8{ab} libsmbclient{a} libtalloc2{a} libtevent0{a} 
  libwbclient0{a} python3-talloc{a} samba-libs{a} 
0 paquetes actualizados, 11 nuevos instalados, 0 para eliminar y 3 sin actualizar.
Necesito descargar 7.763 kB de ficheros. Después de desempaquetar se usarán 33,8 MB.
No se satisfacen las dependencias de los siguientes paquetes:
 libpython3.8 : Depende: libpython3.8-stdlib (= 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) pero 3.8.12-1+bionic1 está instalado
Las acciones siguientes resolverán estas dependencias

     Mantener los paquetes siguientes en la versión actual:
1)     gvfs-backends [Sin instalar]                        
2)     libpython3.8 [Sin instalar]                         
3)     libsmbclient [Sin instalar]                         
4)     python3-talloc [Sin instalar]                       
5)     samba-libs [Sin instalar]                           



¿Acepta esta solución? [Y/n/q/?]^C
```---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Sep 26/2021
enrique@enrique-PC:~$ LC_ALL=C apt-cache policy libpython3.8-stdlib libpython3.8 
libpython3.8-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.8.12-1+bionic1
  Candidate: 3.8.12-1+bionic1
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.12-1+bionic1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libpython3.8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04
  Version table:
     3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
enrique@enrique-PC:~$
````

I followed your last instructions. No complaints from the system. It worked fluidly, I must say that it is like black magic to me! Congratulations and my sincere thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of following commands `dpkg -l | grep -i gvfs`, `apt-cache policy gvfs-backends`, `grep -r "^deb " /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` .

Comment: Please change your repositories to Main Server (*archive.ubuntu.com*), disable proposed updates (*focal-proposed*) and retry with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends` .

Comment: Please add output of `LC_ALL=C apt-cache policy libpython3.8-stdlib libpython3.8` to the question.

Comment: See updated answer below. Reinstall all python3.8 packages using versions from official repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands to fix your *sources.list*:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository restricted

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newest dependencies
```

Then fix your Python versions to match the default Ubuntu repository with current version. Use commands below:

```
sudo aptitude install libpython3.8=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 libpython3.8-minimal=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 libpython3.8-stdlib=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 python3-lib2to3=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 python3.8=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 python3.8-minimal=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04
```

and then finally install the GVFS package

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```

Comment: Thank you, but the result was, same as above, ending with "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  gvfs-backends: Depends: libsmbclient (> = 2: 4.10.0 + dfsg) but it won't install
E: Problems could not be corrected, you have retained broken packages."

Comment: Please install Aptitude by `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and then retry with `sudo aptitude install gvfs-backends` . Please share full error log to pastebin if they occur.

Comment: I followed your "aptitude" recomendation. i edited the result into my initial request (do not know how to use the "pastebin") hope you can see it, Thanks!!!